# how to modify the values of other fields in JDialog box based on the value in combo box

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextfield, jdialog

I am making a dialog box for the application.And I want to fetch the values from the other fields(such as textField) based on the value of combo box. Can anyone please tell me how to link both of these components?
-Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the "other fields" and "combo box" in the same "dialog box"?

Comment: yes both are in the same dialog box.

Comment: See my answer for a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787056/linking-jcombobox-values-with-jtextfield-values/3788729#3788729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no magic methods for just "linking" components together. From your question I understand that you want to interpret data in a textfield based on current choice of a combobox or something like that? So when you read your data, use `JComboBox.getSelectedItem()/getSelectedIndex()` to apply your logic.

If you want to change data in other fields, or disable them, based on a current choice, add a listener:

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int index = combo.getSelectedIndex();
        if (index == 0) {
            //disable some textfields or change format if it's a JFormattedField
        } 
    }
});
```